# remove information when connecting to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Wrote web api on asp.net. When accessing it, information about the server is displayed, how it can be removed.

[image]

Why did you close the question? It contains all the necessary information.

Comment: which framework version are you using? and in your example which url are you accessing?

Comment: 4.7.2 localhost

Comment: I also posted it on the working url I will not show it, but there is the same

Comment: Remove Code from Views/Home/Index.html and Views/Shared/_Layout.html
and write your own

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Controllers` folder and look for the `Home` controller there you will find a method called by default `Index` delete that entry and remove the code from Views/Home/Index.html and Views/Shared/_Layout.html.